# Bounty Points Refund After Grace Period

Tags: support, bounty

So I had put a bounty out on a question and still no viable answers were found. Now that the bounty and grace period has ended, shouldn't I get those points back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, you don't get the reputation back. See [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work) :(

> **What happens if there's no answer after the bounty period?**
>
> **What happens if I feel my question is still unanswered?**
>
> **What is automatic awarding?**
>
> Twenty-four hours after the end of the bounty period, if the bounty
>   starter has not manually awarded the bounty, an eligible answer can be
>   automatically awarded half the bounty amount. The criteria for an
>   answer to be eligible for automatic awarding are as follows:
>
> ```
> The answer must be given after the bounty was started
> The answer must have a score of at least +2
> ```
>
> If two or more eligible answers have the same score, the oldest answer
>   is awarded the bounty.
>
> If no answers meet these criteria, the bounty ends without it being
>   awarded to any answer, and is not refunded to the bounty starter.
>
> An accepted answer that does not meet the above criteria is still
>   ignored by the automatic-awarding system unless it is accepted during
>   the bounty period. An answer accepted during the bounty period will
>   automatically be awarded the full bounty.

Comment: Anyway to change that?  It's really unfortunate that we use that to try to get more attention on a question and the points get wasted.

Comment: Agreed, I had it happen to me on StackOverflow. Probably this won't ever change.. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73548/why-didnt-my-bounty-get-refunded

Comment: There was a discussion somewhere on stackoverflow to change the way it works as now. You still won't get any refund if there is at last one answer but 0 answer question would be refunded. Will try to get that link.

Comment: This just happend to my question now. Is there any update on refunding the bounty points for 0 answer questions??